# Pourrait-on dire ''Il n'y a (pas) quelqu'un'' au lieu de ''il n'y a personne''?

Tags: négation

Quelqu'un m'a posé cette question :

> Peut-on remplacer *personne* dans *il n'y a personne* par *quelqu'un*?

En tant que francophone de naissance, on utilise toujours *personne* dans la forme négative, mais *quelqu'un* dans la forme positive.

Personnellement, ça me semble correct, mais je ne veux pas donner une réponse fausse, car se pourrait-il que *personne* soit exclusivement utilisé pour d'autres raisons?

Comment: Qu'est-ce que tu veux dire par "on utilise pas *quelqu'un* dans la forme positive" ? C'est pas le contraire ?

Comment: Je comprends pas la question. Est-ce que tu veux savoir si on peut dire *quelqu'un* dans la phrase "*il n'y a personne*" ou si il y a d'autres façon d'utiliser *personne* ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Pour le premier commentaire, le ''pas'' s'est glissé par erreur.

Answer (score 4):

Dans cette expression, ce n'est pas possible sans un intérêt de sens ou de style.

Pour plusieurs raisons :

- Elle est bien trop idiomatique;
- Son 2e sens dans un [dictionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/personne#Pronom_ind.C3.A9fini) (partie pronom) :

  > - (*Littéraire*) Quelqu’un.
  >
  >   > *Y a-t-il personne d’assez hardi ?*
  > - **Nul** ; quiconque ; qui que ce soit. — Note : Il est alors accompagné d’une **négation**
  >
  >   > *Je ne connais personne d’aussi heureux que cette femme.*

On parle bien de l'absence de quelqu'un mais ajouter une négation, qui sonne comme inusuelle, alors qu'on peut utiliser un mot tout simplement ... Votre discours ne sera pas considéré comme fluide et naturel.

On peut toujours re-transformer une phrase en utilisant la négation du contraire mais c'est des mots gâchés s'il n'y a pas un intérêt dans la narration; ce sera considéré comme lourd et artificiel.

---

Un [petit texte très sympa](https://fanahy.wordpress.com/2009/09/20/tout-le-monde-quelquun-chacun-et-personne/) sur l'emploi de ces pronoms :

> Sans vouloir le reprocher à Tout le monde,
>
> Il serait bon que Chacun fasse ce qu’il doit sans nourrir l’espoir
>
> Que Quelqu’un le fera à sa place…
>
> Car l’expérience montre que là où on attend Quelqu’un,
>
> Généralement on ne trouve Personne !

Comment: "ajouter une négation qui **sonne** comme **inusuelle** alors qu'on peut utiliser **un mot simplement** ne sera pas considéré **fluide**" looks like a Google translate output.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne sais si je dois me sentir flatté ou pas. Non, j'essaye de transmettre ma pensée, et c'est pas facile... J'ai édité, j'espère que ça parait plus clair...

Comment: «Sonne comme unusuel» n'est pas une expression plausible en français mais un calque de *sounds [as] unusual*. J'écrirais «semble inhabituelle» mais à dire vrai, j'ai du mal à comprendre ce que veut dire cette phrase comme j'ai du mal aussi à comprendre «mais pas quelqu'un dans la forme positive» dans la question…

Comment: @jlliagre La phrase dans la question est, à mon avis, à opposer à l'emploi de *personne* dans la négation : *"Il n'y a personne"* =/= *"Il y a quelqu'un"*. Et j'emploie "sonne" comme dans "Ce discours sonne faux !", et j'ai utilisé *inusuel* plutôt qu'*inhabituel* pour coller à l'*usage* des mots dans la langue.

Comment: Je comprends, mais **inusuel** est quasiment **inusité** en français ;-)

Comment: ''on utilise toujours personne dans la forme négative, mais pas quelqu'un dans la forme positive.'' Le ''pas'' n'aurait pas dû être ici, car oui on utilise toujours personne dans la forme positive. Je vais le corriger.

Comment: @Archa ok, je supprime cette partie

Comment: @jlliagre juste pour le plaisir que tu as pu prendre à faire cette phrase, ça valait le coup !

Answer (score 3):

Cette question est amusante parce que si sa réponse était positive, elle reproduirait exactement un état de langue antérieur (ancien et moyen français) dans lequel la négation **ne** était renforcée par des substantifs désignant des valeurs concrètes et mesurables:

> - Je ne marche *[même un seul]* **pas**.
> - Il n’y a *[même une seule]* **personne**.
> - Tu ne couds *[même un seul]* **point**.
>
> *D’autres mots ainsi utilisés furent par exemple:* **mie**, **goutte**, **rien** *(qui existe encore aujourd’hui pour désigner une très petite quantité: un rien de sel)*, **aucun** *(qui signifiait* quelque *encore au temps de Rabelais).*

À la longue, de nombreuses négations étant ainsi renforcées, ces termes sont devenus si courants, leur lien à la négation si fort, qu’ils devinrent eux-mêmes négatifs. Négatifs au point qu’aujourd’hui, l’oral a presque abandonné le **ne** initial de la négation et fait souvent reposer tout le poids de la négation sur ces termes jadis pleins, aujourd’hui pleins de vide.

En acceptant la proposition d’utiliser «Il [n’]y a pas quelqu’un» (je mets le *n’* entre crochets pour l’oral, qui le laisserait le plus souvent tomber), l’histoire linguistique du français répéterait le modèle «Il n’y a personne».

Et quoique les chances que cela survienne me semblent basses, considérons tout de même la forme interrogative (correcte):

> N’y a-t-il pas quelqu’un?

Answer (score -1):

"Il n'y a pas quelqu'un" ne se dit pas. "pas quelqu'un" = personne.

Ce serait comme dire "plus bon" au lieu de "meilleur".

Comment: Ce n'est pas aussi fermé que pour meilleur, *pas quelqu'un* = *personne* ou *quelques-uns* : plusieurs possibilités. *Il n'y a personne* == *Il n'y a même pas un*

Comment: Je pense que si "Il n'y a pas quelqu'un" n'est pas du bon français, quand on peut utiliser la bonne formulation "il n'y a personne". Essaye de trouver l'occurrence "il n'y a pas quelqu'un" dans un seul livre de littérature. Ce que tu peux trouver c'est "il n'y a pas quelqu'un qui puisse ouvrir la porte ?" par exemple, ce qui n'est pas la même chose, et encore, c'est du langage très parlé.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais dit que cela se disait. Je souligne juste le fait que *"personne"* n'est pas l'exact opposé de *"pas quelqu'un"*. Je suis d'accord avec toi dans l'ensemble mais je trouvais juste ta réponse succincte et ne correspondant pas à l'expression.

Comment: Pour moi, personne = pas quelqu'un.

Comment: Fait. Tout ceci reviens au même. Il n'y a pas quelqu'un = Il n'y a même pas une personne = Il n'y a pas 10 personnes. Ce que je voulais dire avec l'exemple "meilleur", c'est qu'il y a des expressions qui ne s'emploient pas en français, parce qu'un groupe de mots est remplacé par un autre, que ce soit le superlatif "plus bon" qui devient meilleur "ou le "pas quelqu'un" qui devient la "négation" personne, c'est pareil. Si nous ne sommes pas d'accord, eh bien tant pis.

Comment: Bon, je vais détailler car nous sommes d'accord sur le fond, désolé de ne pas l'avoir fait avant. Tu ne peux écrire une égalité lorsque que deux phrases veulent dire des choses différentes. C'est mathématique, pour écrire une égalité à la négation de "Il y a quelqu'un" il faut une expression qui veut dire à la fois qu'il n'y a personne ou alors qu'il y a plus d'une seule personne. *"Il n'y a personne."* en tant que telle, ne recoupe qu'une partie du sens de la négation et ne peut pas être **égal**. `"pas quelqu'un" = personne + ou plus d'un`

Comment: Nous ne sommes pas en mathématiques, je ne pense pas qu'on puisse considérer le signe mathématiques comme une égalité stricte en dehors du domaine mathématique. C'est un peu du chipotage: au lieu d'écrire une égalité, je peux mettre un ":", ça ne pose pas de problème. Des fois j'utilise le signe =>. Mais je ne suis pas d'accord avec le sens possible de "pas quelqu'un" qui pourrait vouloir dire il n'y a pas qu'un seul.