# Ne pas, ne point, ne goutte

Tags: grammaire, expressions, étymologie

Sur ce [lien](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ne-%E2%80%A6%E2%80%AFpoint-ne-%E2%80%A6-pas.86492/), on peut lire ceci:

> Literally:
>
> Je ne vois pas = I do not see a step (footprint)
>
> Je ne vois point= I do not see a dot
>
> Je ne vois goutte = I do not see a drop
>
> Historically, "ne" (= not) was deemed too weak when used on its own,
>   and the complement (pas, point, goutte) was added as a reinforcement.
>
> Not surprisingly in the country of Descartes, only the step (pas)
>   remained popular over time: if you can't see a step, you obviously
>   can't see a dot or a drop...
>
> So, we now end up with two complements: Je ne vois pas la solution = I
>   do not see a step the solution. Strange, mais c'est la vie.

Est-ce correct ?

Quelles références existent qui le confirment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est très approximatif..

Un pas, ce n'est pas un *footprint* (empreinte de pied) mais un *step*.

*Pas* était probablement utilisé à l'origine avec marcher ou avancer :

> Je ne marche pas : *I don't walk a step*
>   Je n'avance pas : *I don't go one step forward*

Les traductions de *point* et *goutte* sont correctes.

> Je **n'y** vois goutte : *I don't see a drop*.

Il y avait aussi *mie*, et d'autres. Certains sont restés en se spécialisant comme *rien*, *personne*, *plus*, *aucun*, *jamais*,  *guère*...

On peut voir comment se sont construits ces adverbes en analysant :

> Qui ne dit **mot** consent.

L'affirmation à propos de Descartes est très probablement sans fondement.

***Pas*** a gagné car c'était probablement le plus simple à prononcer et identifier.

Voir aussi:

[Why does French use a "split negative"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/884/why-does-french-use-a-split-negative)

[Négation avec « point »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/n%C3%A9gation-avec-point)

[Use of 'ne...pas' with 'savoir'](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28901/use-of-ne-pas-with-savoir)

[Should the 2nd Negative Particle be defined positively only?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20096/should-the-2nd-negative-particle-be-defined-positively-only)

[Pourrait-on dire ''Il n'y a (pas) quelqu'un'' au lieu de ''il n'y a personne''?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23484/pourrait-on-dire-il-ny-a-pas-quelquun-au-lieu-de-il-ny-a-personne)

[Est-il acceptable d'omettre « pas » ou « point » après un verbe à la forme négative sans complément ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14466/est-il-acceptable-domettre-pas-ou-point-apr%C3%A8s-un-verbe-%C3%A0-la-forme-n%C3%A9gat)

Comment: Je vous remercie ;)